# Duplicate Order Incremented Order Number After Paypal Express

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.0.1, paypal-express

We have experienced a strange issue that is currently a one off whereby:

- Customer placed an order using PayPal Express Checkout and was refused due to payment method.
- They then amended the order, the order was accepted and created but within 30 seconds a duplicate order was created with the next order number but the customer was not charged twice.

I contacted PayPal and we have determined:

1. The correlation IDs attached to the two orders are related to the same Express Checkout token (EC-5D3489587B7519008)
2. The invoice number for this token was 100001411 but for some reason Magento generated two orders from this payment creating order 100001412 but not charging the customer again.
3. The orders are not related to the initial failed checkout at all.

Our Magento is version 1.9.0.1 and we are due to upgrade to 1.9.1 once the current batch of sales is complete in the next few days.
We are using the standard Magento Paypal Express integration.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happened and how we can avoid this in the future please.